# php logo call in block - Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am building out a site in drupal 7 and running into a ton of problems... very new to drupal here.
I pulled the php call for the logo out of the page.tpl file and put into the header block to be added to all pages. I understand I should probably just leave it in the page.tpl file but thought it made sense to utilize the header block but it is no longer working. can someone explain why this is not working?

here is the code

```
<div id="logo"><?php if ($logo): ?>
      <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo"><img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the variable `$logo` is not available in `block.tpl.php`, it is provided only to `page.tpl.php`.

You can actually grab the values yourself like this:

```
$theme_name = 'name_of_theme';
$settings = variable_get('theme_' . $theme_name . '_settings', array());

if (isset($settings['logo_path'])) {
  $logo = file_create_url($settings['logo_path']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all what you need, it's additions in template.php this code

```
function hook_preprocess_region(&$variables) { 
    $variables['logo'] = theme_get_setting('logo');
    $variables['front_page'] = variable_get('site_frontpage', 'node');
}
```

clear cache

and $logo and $front_page will works good.